# Changed bounded value depending on value in Angular

Tags: angularjs, binding, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat over an array that comes from an $http request. I have a set up to present all details of th array on my site.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
  <h2 id="price">€ {{i.total_price.EUR}}</h2>
  <div class="col-md-12" >
     {{i.changes}}
  </div>
</div>
```

data is the name of the array from the request. `i.changes` gives me a number. However, I want i.changes to output this number except if there is the number 0, then I want it to output 'none' instead of a 0. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use something like this,

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
  <h2 id="price">€ {{i.total_price.EUR}}</h2>
  <div class="col-md-12" >
      {{ (i.changes==0 ? 'none' : i.changes) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

If u get `0` for `i.changes` it check with `(i.changes==0)` and if `i.changes==0` returns true it will print the `none` else it witll print the `i.changes` value

Comment: glad to help u :) cheerz

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
  <h2 id="price">€ {{i.total_price.EUR}}</h2>
  <div class="col-md-12" >
     {{i.changes}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
  <h2 id="price">€ {{i.total_price.EUR}}</h2>
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="i.changes > 0">
     {{i.changes}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="i.changes == 0">
     None
  </div>
</div>
```

That's off the top of my head, so there may be some typos.

Comment: Thanks. Kalhano's answer is a bit more succinct and should probably be accepted over mine!